# How to commit reformatting, so that old commit messages in IDE remain unchanged?

Tags: git

How do I commit changes so that the respective old commit messages are not overwritten, or are there other any best practices for committing non semantic code changes (a.e. reformatting)?

The git plugin in my IDE shows the last commit message which modified the respective line I am currently hovering with my courser, and in some cases the commit message provides useful semantic information. I don't want to overwrite the useful messages with some new commit message a.e. something like 'reformatting'.

I am using GitToolBox in IntelliJ

Comment: You could create a different branch for reformatting and switch between the branches as needed to see the useful information, then merge the two when you're finished. You might wanna make sure the branch not being edited is up to date to avoid merge conflicts. I'm not sure if your IDE would allow you to do that, but the CLI would give you more control.

Comment: Thank @pyknight202 for the reply. I am working with the CLI, I only use the plugin of my IDE (GitToolBox for IntelliJ) to show the commit message of the commit, which most recently modified the specific line of code in the current working branch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not possible and not meant to be in the first place.

The best solution probably would just be copying the information from the commit message to a line comment in code when it happens to be useful or crucial information, otherwise it's probably not important enough in the first place to worry about replacing it.